# why won't my variable value pass onto the url

Tags: javascript, html, url, netsuite

I've spent waaaay too much time trying to make this work.  Is there an html/js superstar who can explain why my code isnt working?

```
  var link = '<a href=\"https://system.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=164&deploy=1&custparamso_id='\"+ recordid +\"'>Approve</a>';
```

Comment: dont excape the quotes

Comment: is recordid server side variable like php or something

Comment: llegal character (sendemlpromo.js#9)  I'll try the suggestion from paulpro and let you know if that works

Comment: I have a link that I want to get passed into an email message into "approve"  I dont want a link, I just want my email to have a link named approve.  This link has a variable in it that needs to be passed when this script is executed.  Everything ive tried either throws me an error, or correctly completes the variable, but parses the rest of the code into the link, making my entire email message an unusable link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var link = '<a href=\"https://system.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=164&deploy=1&custparamso_id='+ recordid +'">Approve</a>';
```

If you want "(quotes) inside a string then you should escape them like this

```
console.log('\"text\"') // will print "text"
```

the mistake in you code was that you did the escaping outside the quotes

Instead you can also use "(double quotes) directly inside the '(single quote)

***edit: additional information***

you can use "(double quotes) with or without escaping inside '(single quote) and vice versa. but when using them together you need to escape them

**valid statements:**

```
console.log(" 'text' ")   // => 'text'
console.log(' "text" ')   // => "text"
console.log(" \"text\" ")  // => "text"
console.log(' \'text\' ')  // => 'text
```

Comment: So will `console.log('"test"')`. No escaping needed here.

Comment: you can use "(double quotes) with or without escaping inside '(single quote) and vice versa. but when use them together you need to escape them

Comment: Yes. But here it isn't the case.

Comment: I've updated the code. It seems to work. Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/NgLrC/

Answer (score 1):

```
var link = '<a ... &custparamso_id=' + encodeURIComponent(recordid) + '>Approve</a>';
```

Comment: I tried that and it now gives me a differnt error about missing the terminating ";" character.  This is now my current code 


 var link = '<a href=\"https://system.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=164&deploy=1&custparamso_id=' + encodeURIComponent(recordid) '">Approve</a>';

Comment: @LightweightHeavyHanded According to your current code, you didn't try the above, as you left out a `+` sign, not to mention you added a `;` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

dont escape the quotes.

it wokrs fine without it

`var link = '<a href="https://system.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=164&deploy=1&custparamso_id='+ recordid +'">Approve</a>';`

http://jsfiddle.net/s6Bej/

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be :

```
var link = '<a href="https://system.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=164&deploy=1&custparamso_id=' + recordid + '">Approve</a>';
```

(Note that I removed the first escaped double quote that shouldn't be here, and move the second inside the single quotes.)

You must not escape double quotes when inside single quotes. Neither should you escape single quotes when inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = "<a href=\"https://... &custparamso_id=" + recordid + "\">Approve</a>
```